# Failed to get the disabled property of an input relative to a select element

Tags: jquery

I've tried to use jQuery to get the 'disabled' property of an input element relative to a select input. But it failed.

My HTML is:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" onchange="toggle_sell()">
            <option>Hold</option>                           
            <option>Trade</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input id="sell-input" class="form-control" type="number" min="0.005" step="0.005" disabled value="123"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to achieve that using jquery:

```
function toggle_sell(){
    var is_disabled = $(this).closest('tr').find('#sell-input').prop('disabled');
    alert (is_disabled);
}
```

When i execute the function, the result only shows "undefined". What is the problem with my code?

Comment: In what way did it fail? What did you get as a result?

Comment: A dialog box appears with "undefined". Sorry forgot to include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your function you can use this code:

```
function toggle_sell(){
     var is_disabled = $(this).closest('tr').find('#sell-input').is('[disabled=disabled]');
     alert (is_disabled );
}
```

Comment: I got FALSE all the time even when i disable the input.

Comment: What do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You will get `attr="disabled"` when it is available , else you will get `undefined`.

```js
$(document).on('change','.togglecell',function(){

 var is_disabled = $(this).closest('tr').find('#sell-input').attr('disabled');
    
    if(is_disabled=='disabled'){
       alert("Disabled");
    }else{
       alert("Not Disabled");
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control togglecell">
            <option value="Hold">Hold</option>            
            <option value="Trade">Trade</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input id="sell-input" class="form-control" type="number" min="0.005" step="0.005" value="123" disabled></td>
    
    
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what your are looking for. Try

```
function toggle_sell(){
    var is_disabled = $('#sell-input').prop('disabled');
    alert (is_disabled);
  }
```